# I want to convert my kotlin code to be like this :

Tags: kotlin

**Hello please help me I have this code**

```
private fun veriKaynaginiDoldur() {
    var images = arrayOf(R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3)
    var names = arrayOf("name 1", "name 2", "name 3")

    for (i in 0..images.size - 1) {
        var eklenecekDost = Dost(names[i], images[i])
        tumDostlar.add(eklenecekDost)
    }


}
```

**I want to convert to be organized like this exapmle **

```
.......add (R.drawable.image1,"name 1").......add (R.drawable.image2,"name 2").......add (R.drawable.image3,"name 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html):

```
private fun veriKaynaginiDoldur() {
    var images = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    var names = listOf("name 1", "name 2", "name 3")

    names.zip(images).forEach { (name, image) ->
        tumDostlar.add(Dost(name, image))
    }
}
```

---

Helper code to make the example compile:

```
data class Dost(val name: String, val image: Int)

class TumDostlar {
    fun add(dost: Dost): Unit {}
}

val tumDostlar = TumDostlar()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but no like so I want when I want to write the code must write  ("image","name") the image near the text because we working for a Dictionary and there is about 3000words it will complicated to use this code , please help me please

Comment: In your code, your `add()` function accepts `Dost` objects. Sorry, but I don't think I can help more unless you provide a working example, and clearly state what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you sir for help i solved the code using your solution like so :private fun veriKaynaginiDoldur() {
    var images = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    var names = listOf("name 1", "name 2", "name 3")

    names.zip(images).forEach { (name, image) ->
        tumDostlar.add(Dost(name, image))
        tumDostlar.add(Dost(name, image))
        tumDostlar.add(Dost(name, image))
    }
}